# bash command to change title of screen window (inside the screen session)

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I want to set the title of the current screen window (inside the screen session) via a bash command.

I know it can be done via C-a A, but that does not work directly as a shell command.

```
screen -t <mytitle> <args>
```

in the current window works, but it creates a new window. I want to rename the current window.

All the posts I saw either dealt with doing this outside a running screen session, or used the screen keybindings/commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your ~/.bashrc file in gedit

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following function at the end of the file.

```
# function to set terminal title
function settitle(){
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
      ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

Rerun the bashrc file to make changes effective in the current terminal. This won't be needed afterwards.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now using the function rename the terminal name from the shell. From the shell type

```
settitle hello
```

This will name it hello.

Answer (score 0):

I used a variant of R.k. Lohana's answer that uses python.

```
import os;
if __name__=='__main__':
 title=sys.argv[1]
 info=r'echo -n "\033k%s\033\\"' %(title)
 os.system(info)
```